# What is the number of non-compact generators of $\operatorname{so}(p, q)$ and $\operatorname{su}(p, q)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Setting $n = p + q$, the total number of generators of $\operatorname{so}(p, q)$ or $\operatorname{su}(p, q)$ is  respectively $n(n - 1) /2$ and $n^2 - 1$.

But what is the number of non-compact generators of $\operatorname{so}(p,q)$ and $\operatorname{su}(p,q)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by generators. Are you asking about dimensions? About roots?

Comment: A Lie algebra is a vector space with a bracket operation, so the generators are simply the basis of this vector space. The Killing form tells us with generator is compact or non compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in a book of Robert Gilmore - Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, asnd some of Their Applications - DOVER EDITIONS - pages 412/414

$$\operatorname{so}(p, q)$$

Number of compact generators :         $\frac{p(p-1) +q(q-1)}{2}$

Number of Noncompact generators :        $pq$

$$\operatorname{su}(p, q)$$

Number of compact generators :         $p^2 + q^2 - 1$

Number of Noncompact generators :        $2 pq$